# Open XML change fontsize of table

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    var tr = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow();
    for (var j = 0; j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        var tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();

        tc.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(data[i, j]))));


        tr.Append(tc);

    }
    table.Append(tr);
}
```

I want to change fontsize in table cell. Can you help me with that? I don't know why they didn't add a property for cell fontsize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the fontsize of a table cell, you need to add a `RunProperties` to the  `Run`.  The fontsize is specified inside a `FontSize` element inside that [RunProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runproperties(v=office.15).aspx).

For example to change all of your entries to fontsize 18, your code would look like:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    var tr = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow();
    for (var j = 0; j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        var tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();

        var paragraph = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph();
        var run = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run();
        var text = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(data[i, j]);

        // your old code for reference:  tc.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(data[i, j]))));

        RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
        FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize(){ Val = "36" };
        runProperties1.Append(fontSize1);

        run.Append(runProperties1);
        run.Append(text);

        paragraph.Append(run);
        tc.Append(paragraph);

        tr.Append(tc);

    }
    table.Append(tr);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I saw a lot of pages with that code, but didnt know, that it will works for me too. thank you very much.

Comment: now i tried to change the font with
RunFonts fonts = new RunFonts();
                        fonts.Ascii = "Arial";
                        fonts.HighAnsi = "Arial";
                        runProperties1.Append(fonts);
and nothing happened...

Comment: you should check out the OpenXML productivity tool - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/openxml/6967/getting-started-with-openxml/28257/using-open-xml-sdk-2-5-productivity-tool .  Create the document how you want it and reverse engineer it with this tool and it will tell you the correct code to use to get your desired font.

Comment: Is there any way to set the font size if the cell is empty? See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536259/how-to-set-font-size-in-empty-cell-in-openxml-word-table)